# How to sort array of objects based on specific alphabet?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I would like to sort and put first the specific key/value pairs in an array of objects and others afterward.

I have found a lot of solutions to sort based on the key or property but haven't seen to pass the specific letter in this function.

```js
let users = [
  { user: 'fred', age: 48 },
  { user: 'barney', age: 36 },
  { user: 'mac', age: 40 },
  { user: 'micheal', age: 34 }
];

users.sort(function(a, b){
  return a.user === b.user ? 0 : a.user.startsWith('m') < b.user ? -1 : 1;
})

console.log(users); // planning to sort user with m and move them first
//expected output

// let users = [
  // { user: 'mac', age: 40 },
  // { user: 'macheal', age: 34 },
//   { user: 'fred', age: 48 },
//   { user: 'barney', age: 36 },
// ];
```

Comment: `a.user.startsWith('m') < b.user` doesn't make much sense to me.  You are comparing a boolean with a string??  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to:**

- Check **both** of the values to see if they begin with `'m'`
- If both of the values begin with `'m'` then compare them alphabetically
- Switch the values of the ordering criteria, to quote MDN:

> **MDN Web Docs:**
>
> ```js
> function compare(a, b) {
>  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
>    return -1;
>  }
>  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
>    return 1;
>  }
>  // a must be equal to b
>  return 0;
> }
> ```

You previously had these the wrong way around.

**Full code:**

```js
let users = [ { user: "mac", age: 40 }, { user: "fred", age: 48 }, { user: "barney", age: 36 }, { user: "micheal", age: 34 }, ];

users.sort(function (a, b) {
  let [aStartsWithM, bStartsWithM] = [a.user.startsWith("m"), b.user.startsWith("m")];
  if (aStartsWithM && bStartsWithM) return a.user < b.user ? -1 : 1;
  else if (aStartsWithM && !bStartsWithM) return -1;
  else return 1;
});

console.log(users);
```

### Regarding your comment:

I made the function that you specified but there are a few things to note about it.

- It assumes all objects are one-dimensional
- It defaults to looking at the first object value when, both objects pass the condition.

**Full code:**

```js
let users = [ { user: "fred", age: 48 }, { user: "barney", age: 36 }, { user: "mac", age: 40 }, { user: "micheal", age: 34 }, ];

function sortBy(array, value) {
  return array.sort(function (a, b) {
    let [aHasValue, bHasValue] = [Object.values(a).find((val) => val?.startsWith?.(value)), Object.values(b).find((val) => val?.startsWith?.(value))];
    if (aHasValue && bHasValue) return a[Object.keys(a)[0]] < b[Object.keys(b)[0]] ? -1 : 1;
    else if (aHasValue && !bHasValue) return -1;
    else return 1;
  });
}

console.log("sortBy 'm'", sortBy(users, "m"));
console.log("sortBy 'barney'", sortBy(users, "barney"));
console.log("sortBy 'mac'", sortBy(users, "mac"));
console.log("sortBy 'fr'", sortBy(users, "fr"));
```

Comment: thanks a lot, what if i want sort based on value instead of considering key?

Comment: For example, not considering user but directly considering value starts with m

Comment: @Bravo I don't understand what you mean, can you give me an example?

Comment: I mean creating a function that will sort based on the value instead of a key (independent of key), so function sortby("mac") will check for the values in the array of objects and move the matched record at first

Comment: @Bravo I've made an edit to my post with the function that you specified .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to maintain the order of the remaining users after moving all "m" to the top, you just return 0 for the others. You need to return `1` or `-1` depending if it's `a` or `b` that starts with "m":

```js
let users = [
  { user: 'fred', age: 48 },
  { user: 'barney', age: 36 },
  { user: 'mac', age: 40 },
  { user: 'micheal', age: 34 }
];

const compareString = (aUser,bUser) => aUser > bUser ? 1 : aUser < bUser ? -1 : 0;
  
users.sort(function(a, b){

  if(a.user.startsWith("m"))
      return b.user.startsWith("m") ? compareString(a.user,b.user) : -1;
  if(b.user.startsWith("m"))
      return a.user.startsWith("m") ? -compareString(a.user,b.user) : 1;
  return compareString(a.user,b.user);
})

console.log(users);
```

Comment: but mac should come first instead of micheal

Comment: @Bravo why should mac come first? Are you saying you want to alphabetically sort all "m's" and then all the rest?

Comment: @Bravo see if this now does what you expect. orders all "m's" alphabetically first then all others alphabetically